# notifyDataSetChanged() not working for SearchView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to implement a `SearchView` in the `ActionBar`. I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the Adapter but the `Fragment` is not getting updated. I am using the debugger, it seems that the flow is working fine but only the `Fragment` is not running again. Here is my code:

This is my Adapter class:

```
public class DessertAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DessertAdapter.DessertVh> {


private List<Dessert> desserts = new ArrayList<>();
OnItemClickListener clickListener;
private Context context;

public DessertAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    desserts = Dessert.prepareDesserts(
            context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dessert_names),
            context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dessert_descriptions));
}

public void setFilter(ArrayList<Dessert> newList){
    desserts = new ArrayList<>();
    desserts.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public DessertVh onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_dessert, parent, false);
    return new DessertAdapter.DessertVh(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DessertVh holder, int position) {
    Dessert dessert = desserts.get(position);

    holder.mName.setText(dessert.getName());
    holder.mDescription.setText(dessert.getDescription());
    holder.mFirstLetter.setText(String.valueOf(dessert.getFirstLetter()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return desserts == null ? 0 : desserts.size();
}

public class DessertVh extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mDescription;
    private TextView mFirstLetter;

    public DessertVh(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        mDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
        mFirstLetter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_firstletter);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}
}
```

This is my Activity class, that consist of Fragment and FragmentPagerAdapter as well:

```
public class TabsHeaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
private static final String TAG = TabsHeaderActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs_header);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.htab_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TECHNOLOGY");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.htab_viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.htab_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.htab_collapse_toolbar);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.edtech);
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                int vibrantColor = palette.getVibrantColor(R.color.primary_500);
                int vibrantDarkColor = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(R.color.primary_700);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(vibrantColor);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(vibrantDarkColor);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if Bitmap fetch fails, fallback to primary colors
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: failed to create bitmap from background", e.fillInStackTrace());
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary_500)
        );
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary_700)
        );
    }

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            Log.d(TAG, "onTabSelected: pos: " + tab.getPosition());

            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    // TODO: 31/03/17
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.cyan_50)), "Cyan");
    adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.amber_50)), "Amber");
    adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_50)), "Purple");
    adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey)), "Grey");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.menuSearch:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    newText = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<Dessert> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Dessert dessert : Dessert.desserts){
        String name = dessert.getName().toLowerCase();
        if(name.contains(newText)){
            newList.add(dessert);
        }
    }

    new DessertAdapter(getBaseContext()).setFilter(newList);
    return true;
}

private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}

public static class DummyFragment extends Fragment{
    int color;
    Intent intent;
    DessertAdapter adapter;

    public DummyFragment() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public DummyFragment(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container, false);

        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_bg);
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_scrollableview);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new DessertAdapter(getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
return view;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling set filter on a new instance of DessertAdapter instead of the adapter instance you set to your recyclerview.

You should define an interface in DummyFragment that allows the activity to deliver the search view query to it.

Then call setFilter on the DessertAdapter instance already instantiated in the fragment.

Comment: That make sense. But how can I deliver the search view query to the interface of DummyFragment.

Comment: Can you please provide me with some examples? @luca992